# This form is not showing on mobile view

Tags: html, css

this form is not showing on mobile view and tab view

```
<form method="post" action="search_file.php"
    class="header-search hs-expanded hs-round d-none d-md-flex input-wrapper">
    <div class="select-box">
        <select id="category" name="category">
            <option value="">Entire Nepal</option>
            
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search For Anything..."
        required />
    <button class="btn btn-search" type="submit" name="submit"><i class="w-icon-search"></i>
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Bootstrap?

```
<form class="header-search hs-expanded hs-round d-none d-md-flex input-wrapper">
```

check your form class. There's `d-none d-md-flex` change it to `d-flex` if you want to show it on all screen sizes

Comment: yap its work thanks